# dotnet core - docker - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to call an api on my .net core application which saves something into my database, when I run my application regularly it is ok but when I run it with docker entityframework shows this error :

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     command: --lower_case_table_names=1
     environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: onlinesmlogs
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true" 
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       - _MySQL_Init_Script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
   onlinesm.logs:
     image: onlinesm
     build: 
       context:  .
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
volumes:
  dbdata: {}
  _MySQL_Init_Script : {}
```

and here is my connection string:

```
"server=127.0.0.1;port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd="
```

Comment: If the connection string is not used inside the docker container, the mysql host in not reachable since the mysql port is not exposed. Add a port mapping or use the containers IP instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: when I run docker inspect it returns no value because as it says in this link https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35750 there is no portmapping

Comment: Did anyone figure out an answer for this?